# Downloading file from Symfony App / vue - htaccess misconfig?

Tags: vue.js, symfony, .htaccess

I have a Symfony 6 backend which basically serves as a REST API to a vue 3 application.
Both run on a Debian system with Apache2 as Webserver.

The vue app runs in the base folder, whereas the API is placed in a subfolder /api.

I am using following htaccess files:

var/www/html/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

/var/www/html/api/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

This works fine. Now I want to download a PDF, which I send as a normal response in a route.

```
return 
        new Response(
            $pdf, 
            Response::HTTP_OK, 
            [ 
                'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf', 
                'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="report.pdf"' 
            ]
        );
```

It is downloaded via a link in my vue app:

```
<a :href="cfg.apiUrl + '/report' + query" target="_blank">
    <button class="btn btn-success">
        Download PDF
    </button>
</a>
```

This also works fine when I run it on my local test server! But when I click on it on the live-server, it opens a new tab with the menu of the vue app and the VueRouter part being empty. On the local server however it opens the tab and displays the PDF!

Update:
I can download the PDF when inserting the route in POSTMAN... just not via the vue app.